# Functions with loops & multiples in R

Tags: r

I'm still getting to grips with R and have been set the task of specifically writing a function where if `x` and `y` are vectors:

```
x <- c(3,7,9) 
y <- 20
```

...then all of `x` and multiples of `x` which are less than `y` need to be output in the form of a vector, e.g.:

```
v1 <- c(3,6,7,9,12,14,15,18)
```

But then within the function it needs to sum up all the numbers in the vector `v1` - `(3+6+...+15+18)`.

I've had a go at it but I can never really get my head around if else statements, so could anyone help me out and explain so I know for future reference?

Comment: Next time when you post a question add what you've tried so far. Check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8904662/simple-if-else-loop-in-r) more on `if else` in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No loops needed. Figure out how many times each `x` value goes into `y`, then generate a list of the unique numbers:

```
x <- c(3,7,9)
y <- 20

possible <- y %/% x
#[1] 6 2 2

out <- unique(sequence(possible) * rep(x,possible))
# or alternatively
# out <- unique(unlist(Map(function(a,b) sequence(a) * b, possible, x)))
out
#[1]  3  6  9 12 15 18  7 14
sum(out)
#[1] 84
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using basic loops and if else branching in R.

```
x <- c(3,7,9)
y1 <- 20
v1 <- numeric()
for(i in x){
    nex <- i
    counter <- 1
    repeat{
        if(!(nex %in% v1)){
            v1 <- c(v1, nex)
        }
        counter <- counter + 1
        nex <- i*counter
        if(nex >= y1){
            break
        }
    }
}
v1 <- sort(v1)
v1.sum <- sum(v1)

v1 
## 3  6  7  9 12 14 15 18
v1.sum
## 84
```