# if else loop not working

Tags: if-statement, matrix, variable-assignment

I am a beginner in R studio, so hopefully someone can help me with this problem. *The case:* I want to make an if else loop. I made the following code  for an `l` times `m` matrix:

```
for (i in 1:l){
  for (j in 1:m){ 
    if (is.na(quantilereturns[i,j]) < quantile(quantilereturns[,j], c(.1), na.rm=TRUE)) { 
      quantilereturns[i,j]    
    } else { (0) }
  }
}
```

*Summary:* I want to make a matrix with values that are smaller than the quantile of a certain vector in the matrix `quantilereturns`. So when they are smaller than the 10% quantile they get their original value otherwise it will be a zero. 
The code doesn't give any errors, but it doesn't change the values in the matrix either. 
Can someone help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple if-else loop in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8904662/simple-if-else-loop-in-r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the result to a cell of the matrix. I will take the matrix of a recent other thread as an example:

```
a <- c(4, -9, 2)
b <- c(-1, 3, -8)
c <- c(5, 2, 6)
d <- c(7, 9, -2)
matrix <- cbind(a,b,c,d)

d <- dim(matrix)
rows <- d[1]
columns <- d[2]

print("Before")
print(matrix)

for (i in 1:rows) {
  for (j in 1:columns) {
    if (is.na(matrix[i,j]) >= quantile(matrix[,j], c(.1), na.rm=TRUE)) {
      matrix[i,j] <- 0
    }
  }
}

print("After")
print(matrix)
```

this gives

```
[1] "Before"
      a  b c  d
[1,]  4 -1 5  7
[2,] -9  3 2  9
[3,]  2 -8 6 -2
[1] "After"
     a b c d
[1,] 0 0 5 0
[2,] 0 0 2 0
[3,] 0 0 6 0
```

So the essential line you are looking for is `matrix[i,j] <- 0`